# Why matter can arise also in solid phase besides to the liquid and gaseous phase?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Is there an explaination why solids can exist besides liquids, gases and plasmas?

Comment: It bit more information about your thinking will probably get you a better answer. Why do you find the existence of liquids gasses and plasmas more obvious than solids?